# Pass typescript's interface to react state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

I am new in TypeScript. I want to pass the typescript's interface to react state and then render the state. But I don't know how to pass the interface value to react state.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export interface Person {
  name: name
  age: age
}

type name = "John"
type age = 30
const Test = () => {

  const [state, setstate] = useState() //I want to pass the interface in here
  return (
    <div>
    <p> He is {state.name} and he is {state.age} years old</p> 
    </div>
  )
}
export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an object that matches the interface, and pass that into `useState`, like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({name: "John", age: 30});
```

You can also be explicit about the type of that state variable, because `useState` is generic:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<Person>({name: "John", age: 30});
```

but you don't have to be. TypeScript's type checking is structural, not nominal,¹ meaning that any object with appropriately-matching properties is a match for the state.

If you may not have a person, allow `null` or `undefined`:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<Person | null>(null);
// or
const [state, setState] = useState<Person | undefined>(undefined);
```

In that case, since the type would be `null` or `undefined` if it were just inferred from what you pass into `useState`, you need the generic type parameter on the call.

---

¹ For me, this concept was foundational in TypeScript. It's not so much that something *is a* type as it is in (say) Java, it's that something *matches* a type. This is perfectly valid TypeScript:

```
interface A {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
interface B {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
let a: A = {name: "Joe", age: 27};
let b: B;
b = a;
```

It doesn't matter that `b` is declared as type `B` and `a` is declared as type `A`, you can do `b = a;` because `a`'s type is structurally compatible with `b`'s type (in this case, they're identical).

This is also perfectly valid:

```
interface A {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    rank: string;
}
interface B {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
let a: A = {name: "Joe", age: 27, rank: "Junior Petty Officer"};
let b: B;
b = a;
```

It's okay that `a`'s type has a property (`rank`) that `b`'s type doesn't have. It's still compatible with `b`'s type.

Comment: *(Doh! Of course this is a duplicate question. Since I'd already done the answer, I've marked it a community wiki rather than deleting it.)*

Answer (score 0):

You can define the interface type with useState like

```
const [state, setstate] = useState<Person>({name: "John", age: 30 });
```

Be sure to provide the intialState according to Person type property. If instead you define an empty object you could write it like

```
const [state, setstate] = useState<Person>(Object);
```

Also you could specify useState type to be null or undefined by explicitly defining it

```
const [state, setstate] = useState<Person | undefined>();
```

and

```
const [state, setstate] = useState<Person | null>(null);
```